# Is this translation of Donald Trump's tweet by ‘Der Spiegel’ correct?

Tags: translation

I came across an [article](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/davidstern-donald-trump-hat-ein-israel-problem-a-1101302.html) in *Der Spiegel*, in which a translation of Donald Trump's tweet was made. Here is the sentence from the article that provides some context:

> Mit einem Stern vor Banknoten, der dem Davidstern ähnelt, wollte Donald Trump seine Rivalin Hillary Clinton als korrupte Politikerin darstellen.

Here's the image that appeared in Donald Trump's original tweet (the one to the right):

[image]

After that image draw some criticism, Donald Trump [tweeted](http://www.nbcnews.com/politics/2016-election/donald-trump-s-star-david-tweet-about-hillary-clinton-posted-n603161):

> "Dishonest media is trying their absolute best to depict a star in a tweet as the Star of David rather than a Sheriff's Star, or plain star!"

*Der Spiegel* translated the above tweet in this manner:

> "Die verlogenen Medien", so der Milliardär, "geben ihr Bestes, um einen Stern in einem Tweet zum Davidstern zu machen und zum Sheriff-Stern oder ganz normalen Stern."

So, is the translation correct? Der Spiegel translates "rather than" as "und". With such a translation the sentence seems to be unclear.

Comment: Yes, that blurb was translated wrong. I don't think it makes any more sense if translated right, though.

Comment: @tofro Well, the current translation doesn't make any sense at all. *[..] a Star of David **and** a Sheriff's Star or plain star* is meaningless. That said, Trump's post is nonsense semantically, though not grammatically.

Comment: I know it's not the question here, but isn't the translation of _dishonest_ to _verlogen_ a little bit extreme? In my eyes there's quite a difference between _verlogen_ and _unehrlich_...

Comment: What*'s the left picture, BTW? You're not mentioning anything about it?

Comment: The on-line article has since been corrected: it now reads "zum Davidstern zu machen _statt_ zum Sheriff-Stern oder ganz normalen Stern."

Comment: @tofro The picture at the left is the edited version of the picture at the right: "Most Corrupt Candidate Ever" is now encircled instead of en-starred. The edition is the result of the criticism of the picture at the right.

Comment: @TonyK Someone at "Spiegel.de" seems to be reading SE GL, apparently ;)

Comment: I wonder why it should be a problem for Trump to see his star being described as (resembling) a star of David?

Comment: @Jan This is what the article says: "Aber um in dem Bild eine stereotype Verknüpfung von Geld und Juden zu erkennen, musste man wahrlich keine kunsthistorische Ausbildung genossen haben."

Comment: Oh that’s why. I choose to ignore these types of stereotypes so strongly, that I miss them when they punch me in the eye. Not sure if I’m allowed to be proud of myself now xD

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, it is not.

The translation should be something like

> "Die verlogenen Medien", so der Milliardär, "geben ihr Bestes, um einen Stern in einem Tweet zum Davidstern zu machen *als vielmehr*/*anstatt* zu einem Sheriff-Stern oder ganz normalen Stern."

Their translation changes the meaning from "rather than" to "and", so the reader understands that the media wanted to depict the star as all a star of David, a sheriff's and a normal star. Thus the tweet loses its intent.

Comment: Vorschlag anstelle von "als vielmehr": "anstatt"

Comment: Yes, "rather than" definitely has to be "anstatt", since we're talking about a categorical difference and not one of degree.

Answer (score 13):

### On the actual mistake

The translation isn't as bad as others I've encountered.
A simple "nicht" ("not") added at the right place makes it a valid (although not accurate) translation:

> "Die verlogenen Medien", so der Milliardär, "geben ihr Bestes, um einen Stern in einem Tweet zum Davidstern zu machen und **nicht** zum Sheriff-Stern oder ganz normalen Stern."

It can be an honest mistake and actually triggered my head-internal auto-correction: I read it as the corrected form and just noted a missing "nicht". Reading lots of low quality texts in different languages kind of hardens you for something as simple. It also carries no connotation making a simple mistake very likely.

### More into details

I would see "Die verlogenen" as a somewhat inaccurate translation of "Dishonest". "Unehrliche" much better captures the degree of dishonesty, which Trump accuses them of. Sad to say but this translational mistake carries connotation and **could** be more than a mistake. While we established that the translation is not good, this can be seen as actual dishonesty. It's still not a lie though. They just overstated their opponent's position. I guess that's a stone Trump (or any politician for that matter) shouldn't be throwing.

### For the original media text

> Mit einem Stern vor Banknoten, der dem Davidstern ähnelt, wollte Donald Trump seine Rivalin Hillary Clinton als korrupte Politikerin darstellen.

"der dem Davidstern ähnelt" should be translated as "which resembles the Star of David". It's not like they are depicting anything that isn't there. They state an obvious resemblance. The only difference I can make out is that the Star of David is usually just lines and no filled area.

If Sheriff's Stars have six pointy corners, straight edges and are oriented (see text orientation) to rest on a single corner, they do resemble the Star of David, too. I remember Sheriff's Stars with five or six corners, which have small balls instead of points. Those with six corners may still mutually resemble the Star of David and the depicted star.
On one hand **plain** stars are usually five-cornered, straight-edged and stand on two corners. At least that's the most plain star I've seen yet. Plus it doesn't beg for misinterpretations.
On the other hand it could be **plain** (like "just") "any star with 6 corners" instead of any "plain star". That would actually make more sense than a Sheriff's Star.

### Funny enough

> History
>   made.

Who else sees the connotation of "Fairytales fabricated."?

> (Hi)story => German "Geschichte" => 
>   "Geschichte**n**" => Fairytales
>
> made (up) => fabricated

Comment: "dishonest" == "verlogen" is admittedly not the first translation that comes to mind - But it is not "inaccurate" as you say - It is entirely correct. Whether it was the original intention of DT, we cannot say (And, thinking about it, there's not much of a difference in meaning between "unehrlich" and "verlogen" - After all, Duden even sees "betrügerisch" as a synonym for "unehrlich" and "unaufrichtig" as one for "verlogen" - Although this differes from my personal sense of gradience of dishonesty ;) ). Apparently, the distinction is not very clear.

Comment: I used "inaccurate" in contrast to "incorrect". The translation of meaning is correct. However I feel there's strong connotation about the magnitude, which the translation doesn't meet accurately. Hence I use "inaccurate". I thought I made that clear with "They just overstated their opponent's position". When translating an opposing point one should be as conservative as possible: "Lying" == "Verlogen", "(Dis)honest" == "(Un)ehrlich". Feel free to edit, if you think you can make that distinction more clear. However I think with translations there's always multiple "valid" interpretations.

Comment: Well, the main point of my answer could be more pronounced: It could be a simple mistake (word left out). Any idea how to make that more clear? **Feel free to edit.** I'd prefer not losing content about connotation, because I consider it an important part of translations although it's often a source of disagreement.

Comment: I noticed that I used "very", maybe  "somewhat" is a better qualifier in "somewhat inaccurate translation". Problem is with connotations interpretations vary widely. I think there's a remarkable difference between "lying" and being "dishonest". I try to avoid telling something I know is factually wrong (lying) however I do sometimes enjoy implying things so people draw wrong conclusions on their own (dishonest). Not my fault is it? I still tuned that one down to match a less differentiating interpretation, e.g. a less strict definition of lying.

Comment: What a first post! Welcome!

Comment: @tofro I agree it slightly inaccurate at most. "verlogen" is not as strong as "Lying", which would be "Lügend". I think "verlogen" a softer form of it, matching "dishonest" very well. It is only less formal.

Answer (score 9):

It is not correct. It implies the media *tries* to depict a sheriff star or normal star. They failed to translate the "rather than".